# How to get the index of multiple column in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a table like this:

| cars | John | Mike | Louis | John |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BMW | x |  |  |  |
| Benz |  | x |  |  |
| Nissan |  |  |  | x |
| Honda |  |  | x |  |

lets's say I have a cell with John name inside I would like to get underneath it :
BMW
Nissan

Using my formula am getting only BMW
my formula: =IFERROR(FILTER(P4:P7, INDEX(Q4:T7, 0, MATCH(P9, Q3:T3, 0))="x"))
sure cause MATCH returns one index which is the first john, any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following formula-

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,FILTER(A2:A5,BYROW(INDEX((B1:E1=H1)*(B2:E5<>"")),LAMBDA(x,OR(X)))))
```

Another approach could be-

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(A2:A5, BYROW(FILTER(B2:E5,B1:E1=H1)="x",LAMBDA(x,OR(x)))))
```

[image]